# How could "Beach2018!" be a valid email address for input type "email"?

Tags: forms, email-validation

I have a signup form with these fields:

```
<input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." required="" id="firstname" class="personHead">
<input type="email" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address..." required="" id="email" class="envelope">
```

Someone recently accidentally typed her email address into the fullName field and some junk ("Beach2018!") into the emailAddress field.

Since the emailAddress field is `type="email"`, I figured its validation rules would be [this regex according to W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/datatypes.html#form.data.emailaddress), which is [supported in almost every browser](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=email).

A [demo fiddle here](https://regex101.com/r/gGQUD7/1) shows that "Beach2018!" is invalid. So I don't know how it submitted successfully.

I have a record of her userAgent, which says "iOS 9.3.5" and "Mozilla/5.0" (plus some other information that might be improper to paste here).

How could the form submission could go through without the `type=email` validation processing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an old iPad 2 ([Model A1395](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471)) running iOS 9.1, and tested the form using Google Chrome (which probably uses the same engine as Safari):

There seemed to be no validation for the `type=email` field.

P.S. When I opened Safari and Googled "what is my usergent", it said Safari/601.1.  I don't know how to compare that to Safari 3-4 listed in https://www.caniuse.com/#search=email.

Comment: I'm sure you've heard this before, but it's always good practice to validate data on the back end as well. Front end validation is useful for faster, user friendly messages without having to talk to the server, but the server should never trust that the browser or any front end will properly validate data. There's always ways to circumvent it. I couldn't tell from your initial question if you were performing back end validation already.

Comment: @cost You're right. I've been lazy and haven't been using this yet: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-email